# Trying to save custom object in UserDefaults using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject, nskeyedarchiver, userdefaults

I want to save my custom class object in userdefault.
I'm trying to save it like this:

```
class func setModel<T: Hashable>(model: T, key: String) {
    let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: model)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: key)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

but the app is crashing on the first line of this method with the error:

> NSForwarding: warning: object 0x600003944000 of class 'DronesApp_Worker.WorkerProfileResponse' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[DronesApp_Worker.WorkerProfileResponse replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]

My custom object class is given below:

```
class WorkerProfileResponse: Codable, Hashable, Mappable{

    static func == (lhs: WorkerProfileResponse, rhs: WorkerProfileResponse) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    override var hash: Int{
        return self.id!
    }

    var id, is_logged_in, last_login, last_active: Int?
    var username, email, mobile_number: String?
    var categoryName: String?
    var userCategories: [SelectedCategory]?
    var userSubCategories: [SelectedSubCategory]?
    var biometricToken: String?
    var accessToken: AccessToken?
    var userStatus: UserStatus?
    var userProfile: UserProfile?

    required init(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        is_logged_in <- map["is_logged_in"]
        last_login <- map["last_login"]
        last_active <- map["last_active"]
        biometricToken <- map["biometricToken"]
        username <- map["username"]
        email <- map["email"]
        mobile_number <- map["mobile_number"]
        accessToken <- map["accessToken"]
        userStatus <- map["userStatus"]
        userCategories <- map["userCategories"]
        userSubCategories <- map["userSubCategories"]
        userProfile <- map["userProfile"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `NSKeyedArchiver`, especially since your type is already `Codable` conformant, simply use `PropertyListEncoder` or `JSONEncoder` as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926513/4667835) answer.

Comment: I've changed this line:

```let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: model)```

to this: 

```let encodedData: Data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(model)```

And now it is giving me error:

*Argument type 'T' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'*

Comment: You need to change `T:Hashable` to `T:Encodable` in your `setModel` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **JSONEncoder** to save data to UserDefaults. Dummy code:

```
class YourClassName: Codable {
    //Your properties here

    func saveInPreference() {
        do {
            let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(try jsonEncoder.encode(Your object here), forKey: "Write UserDefaultKey here")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

@Faraz A. Khan comment if you have any questions in the above piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because a subclass of `NSObject` is required.

As I already mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100434/app-crashing-with-error-generic-parameter-t-could-not-be-inferred) to use `NSKeyedArchiver` the class must be a subclass of `NSObject` and must adopt (and implement) **`NSCoding`**.

Once again: `NSKeyedArchiver` (related to ObjC) has nothing to do with `Codable` (related to Swift).